# Jsoup retrieve youtube title

Tags: java, html, regex, youtube, jsoup

What I want to do is simply retrieve the title of a **youtube** page, so far I accomplished this with **Jsoup** by doing

```
title = doc.getElementById("eow-title").text();
```

But now youtube changed it's layout and that tag doesn't exist anymore, I inspected a **youtube** `html` code and found out they now store the **youtube player** title inside of a `<script>` tag, problem is it's in the following form and I have no idea how to retrieve that:

> var ytplayer = ytplayer || {};ytplayer.config =
>   {"messages":{"player_fallback":["Per la riproduzione del video è
>   necessario Adobe Flash Player o un browser HTML5. \u003ca
>   href=\"https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/\"\u003eScarica l'ultima
>   versione di Flash Player \u003c/a\u003e \u003ca
>   href=\"/html5\"\u003eUlteriori informazioni sull'aggiornamento a un
>   browser
>   HTML5\u003c/a\u003e"]},"args":{"vm":"CAIQABgE","iv_invideo_url":"https://www.youtube.com/annotations_invideo?cap_hist=1\u0026video_id=wckFsik_vU8\u0026client=1\u0026ei=JY-2WfHPFIWxcpzcrKAF","watch_xlb":"https://s.ytimg.com/yts/xlbbin/watch-strings-it_IT-vflA6zD4C.xlb","pltype":"contentugc","author":"BrawlBRSTMs3
>   X",**"title":"Big Blue - F-Zero Music
>   Extended"**,"innertube_api_version":"v1","eventid":"JY-2WfHPFIWxcpzcrKAF",

Maybe I could manually parse the title with some `regex`? I don't know enough about `regex` to work something out, please help.

P.S.
I already tried `doc.getTitle();` to no avail, all I get is "Youtube" instead of the full title.

Solved by pleft, i had to edit the code a little bit but this is how i've made it work:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(getLink()).get();
Elements script = doc.select("script");  //to get the script content
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"title\":\"(.+?)\""); // Regex for the getting the string: "title":"blah blah blah" 
Matcher m = p.matcher(script.html());
m.find();
title = m.group().substring(8);
```

Comment: FYI: `doc.getTitle();` get's the text between <title> tag. Which is apparently "YouTube". @pleft 's solution is quite solid!

Comment: it will be even better to use `group(1)`, this way you won't need the `substring()` and the quotes won't be there as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeap `regex` will do the trick. Can you try the following:

```
Element script = doc.select("script").first();  //to get the script content
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"title\":\"(.+?)\""); // Regex for the getting the string: "title":"blah blah blah" 
Matcher m = p.matcher(script.html());

while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try reading the `player` div from the source, and find the `title` from the `script` inside that `div` . Here is the working sample using `JSOUP` . This will print  "title": "Actual Title" .So please update it as you need.

```
  Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lhs_chrfXfE").timeout(10000).get();

    Elements player = doc.select("div#player");

    for(Element e:player){

        Elements scriptContent = e.getElementsByTag("script");

        for (Element paragraph : scriptContent) {
          System.out.println(paragraph.attr("script"));
            for (DataNode node : paragraph.dataNodes()) {
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"title\":\"(.+?)\""); 
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(node.getWholeData());
                if(matcher.find())
                {
                    **//***this is your title*****
                    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
                }

            }

        }

    }


}
```